# Wrong font size in desktop version in Portrait mode on mobile

Tags: support, design

When I am opening the site in desktop version on my mobile<sup>1</sup>, I am getting incorrect font size in portrait mode. Please see below the screenshots of the same page in portraint mode as well as landscape mode:

[image: Portrait 1]
[image: Landscape 1]

[image: Portrait 2]
[image: Landscape 2]

Could someone please help? I think the desktop version should be consistent in all the views. Currently, it has readability problem in the portrait mode especially when the page has some code.

<sub>1. I am using Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on Android 6.0.1 on OnePlus One.</sub>

Comment: I don't believe they support using the desktop version of the site on a mobile browser (and why would they, since they have a mobile version).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - the mobile version of the site lacks many features such text/code formatting and real time update notification. You might tell me to use the stackexchange app, but that has browsing problems. I can't find latest questions in my favourite tags in one go in the app.

Comment: I'm not telling you to *do* anything. I'm just warning you that they don't support the desktop version of the site on mobile browsers, and making the comment that it seems odd to demand that the desktop version work on mobile, when they have a mobile version. If you want to submit a feature request to get parity between the two versions, that's your prerogative, and I think it would get a good amount of support.

Comment: @Mike - I want to do that only. Where can I submit one please?

Comment: Right here on Meta. First, it would be a good idea to read [the tag info for `feature-request`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) just to ensure you give the right info. Then, just "Ask Question" and use the tag [tag:feature-request] on it.

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I'll ask a new question then.